# how to send pm to WhatsApp

Tags: c#, whatsapp

I found an example to send instant messages in C# using Whatsapp.

> https://github.com/perezdidac/WhatsAPINet

this application connects to this address

```
request = string.Format("https://v.whatsapp.net/v2/code?cc={0}&in={1}&to={0}{1}&method={2}&mcc={3}&mnc={4}&token={5}&id={6}&lg={7}&lc={8}", pn.CC, pn.Number, method, pn.MCC, pn.MNC, token, id, pn.ISO639, pn.ISO3166);
```

when run, the application's request is the following

```
https://v.whatsapp.net/v2/code?cc=98&in=9356256952&to=989356256952&method=sms&mcc=432&mnc=035&token=qrlotgzUkVUYr8yBz3aeQt67TiM%3D&id=s%e8%ad%e83%c1%0c%1ap%0a%c8j%f4%f1%c4%2d%eag%e0%85&lg=fa&lc=IR
```

but this results in an error

```
"{\"status\":\"fail\",\"reason\":\"old_version\"}"
```

Comment: Just so you know, most words *aren't* capitalized in English. When you're not sure, it's better not to capitalize.

Comment: i am also encountering the same issue. Where u able to solve this issue? if so please share.

Comment: No I don't solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the error is self-explanatory. The WhatsAPI.NET project is unofficial and the request sent by this port has been superseded by something else (newer version) by WhatsApp. You will either have to use another unofficial API or not use WhatsApp as your messaging back-end in the absence of an official API.

Comment: I searched but could not find much for the new version

Answer (score 0):

vim Yowsup/Common/constants.py

change only

```
    v="0.90"

    tokenData = {
            "v": "2.12.29",
            "r": "S40-2.12.29",
            "u": "WhatsApp/2.12.49 S40Version/14.26 Device/Nokia302",
            "t": "PdA2DJyKoUrwLw1Bg6EIhzh502dF9noR9uFCllGk1413401214298{phone}",
            "d": "Nokia302"
    }
```